# Cannot find MongoDB .msi file

Tags: mongodb, installation

I'm trying to install MongoDB on my computer, and I'm following the instructions as per [this MongoDB documentation](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/tutorial/install-mongodb-on-windows/). Now it talks about double-clicking on the .msi file and follow the installation wizard. My problem is there is no .msi file in the .zip file I downloaded from the [MongoDB download center](https://www.mongodb.com/download-center?jmp=docs#production) (and I tried downloading different versions). Not one of them comes with the .msi file. Where can I find this .msi file?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Simple, I can see it on your link

[image]

Comment: Awesome, got it now. Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

Use this link (direct download): https://downloads.mongodb.com/win32/mongodb-win32-x86_64-enterprise-windows-64-4.0.3-signed.msi?_ga=2.171673253.408195958.1539592259-393430431.1531827969&_gac=1.174902550.1538388030.EAIaIQobChMIxrWG-P3k3QIVS5yzCh0NgwFAEAAYASAAEgKFafD_BwE

Source:https://www.mongodb.com/community/forums/t/not-able-to-select-msi-in-mongodb-download-center/50951/2